# tf.nn.in_top_k: targets out of range

Tags: tensorflow

I adapt the cifar10 network from the tensorflow, to address my own classification problem. I have trained the network and now I try to evaluate the trained model with the cifar10_eval.py

```
top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)
```

But I get following error. After further investigation, the index of target varies between 2,3 and 4

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: targets[3] is out of range
```

By now, I understand that something is wrong with my label-Tensor. It's a int32-Tensor with shape(50,) shown below.

```
labels = {Tensor} Tensor("batch_processing/Reshape_1:0", shape=(50,), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0)
```

My dataset has just 2 classes/labels. Maybe this could be the problem. Does anyone know, what the problem is?

Comment: What is the shape of `logits`?

Comment: the shape of `logits` is shape(50,2)

Comment: Make sure that labels contain only 0 and 1

Comment: Thanks for your advice.... In regards to the documention, the top_k_op tensor has the right type (bool) and size (50). As you mentioned, I suspect that the labels tensor contains more number than 0 and 1. But currently i'am struggle with debugging the labels tensor. I can't see the values of the tensor..

Comment: I summed it up in the answer

Answer (score 7):

To sum it up, the function `tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions, targets, k)` (see the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#in_top_k)) has arguments:

- predictions: shape `[batch_size, num_classes]`, type float32
- targets (the correct label): shape `[batch_size]`, type int32 or int64

---

The function raises the error `InvalidArgumentError: targets[i] is out of range` when the element `targets[i]` is out of range in `predictions[i]`.

For instance, there are 2 classes (`num_classes=2`) and `targets=[1, 3]`. 
With these targets, you will see an error `InvalidArgumentError: targets[1] is out of range` because `targets[1] = 3` is out of range for `predictions[1]` which has only shape 2.

---

To check that your `labels` are correct, you can print the max of them:

```py
labels = ...
labels_max = tf.reduce_max(labels)

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(labels_max)
```

If the value printed is superior to `num_classes`, you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

So if you would have your predictions in something like one hot encoding , your targets must be the right index where your one (1) hot would be placed.
For example this:

```
bb=tf.nn.in_top_k([[0,1],[1,0],[0,1]]  ,   [1,1,1],1)
```

will return:

[ True False  True]

So to answer, you must to convert your probably one hot targets to this index method

Numpy:

```
targetsindex = np.argmax(targets, axis=1)
```

Tensor:

```
targetsindex = tf.argmax(targets, axis=0)
```